# Site breaks after adding Masonry to WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm trying to add masonry to my woocommerce shop page in a twentytwelve child theme. This is also the frontpage of my site. I'm fairly new to PHP and Wordpress.

The first step was to create a function to load the masonry.pkgd.min.js file from http://masonry.desandro.com/

This is the function:

```
function twentytwelve_child_masonry() {
if (! is_admin()) {
    wp_register_script('jquery_masonry', get_stylesheet_directory_uri(). 'js/masonry.pkgd.min.js' ,array(jquery), 3.2 );
    wp_enque_script('jquery_masonry');
    add_action('wp_footer', 'twentytwelve_child_add_masonry');        
    function twentytwelve_child_add_masonry() { ?>
        <script> 
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $('#content').masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.products',
            isAnimated: true;
                }); });
        </script>
    <?php
  }}}
add_action('init', 'twentytwelve_child_masonry');
```

I found it in a tutorial at Lynda.com about building responsive themes.
When I try to load the page the site crashes. Anyone any idea? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Websites don't "crash". What what actually went wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't enqueue scripts in the `init` action. Actually, if you turn on debug, you'll see an error.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Loading the page it gives me a white screen. In the admin area of Wordpress also. the function starts however with if (! is_admin())...

Comment: If !is_admin just means it'll only be shown to people who aren't logged in as admins. A white screen is probably a 500 error on the server. Look in your error log.

Comment: You've got a typo, `wp_enque_script` should be `wp_enqueue_script`. Also, masonry is shipped with WP, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress

Comment: Thank you both for commenting. Debugging the file in NetBeans learns me that there is indeed a 500 error on the server (localhost, MAMP). I figured out that when i remove the "init" statement the page shows but the script is not loaded (as far as i can tell).

Comment: @i-CONICA...`is_admin()` actually checks if the Dashboard or the administration panel is attempting to be displayed. You should [read the docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin)

Comment: I was explaining the logic of the exclamation mark, not what that method actually does. I've not used WP in years, so I'm foggy. Either way it was a 500 error caused by an undefined function call, as I said.

Comment: If you found that code in a tutorial, you should really stop following it immediately. There are MANY errors with it, including nesting functions and incorrect use of WordPress functions, among other things.

Comment: Thank you both again. The logic of the exclamation mark is known. @mevius: OK I will stop. But how do I get my shop frontpage in masonry style? I did not understand the explanation on masonry.desandro.com. Tried plug-ins as well but they did not give me the result I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix some syntax errors, stop nesting functions, use [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) properly, and enqueue the scripts at the proper moment. You can't (or shouldn't) enqueue them with the `init` action. Instead, you really should simplify things like the following:

```
function twentytwelve_child_masonry() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery_masonry', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.2', true );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'twentytwelve_child_masonry');
```

Then, add the following to your **footer.php**:

```
<script> 
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#content').masonry({
            itemSelector: '.products',
            isAnimated: true;
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

However, as mentioned, Masonry ships with WordPress...so this is still probably complicating things.

Comment: OP uses child theme, should be `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Comment: I understand indeed that it has tob e get_stylesheet_directory_uri() because of the child theme. @mevius: do you mean what James Koster wrote on his blog? This code?add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jk_masonry' );
function jk_masonry() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-masonry', array( 'jquery' ) );
} I'm truly confused.

Comment: @diggy edited. Totally missed that part...even though the function even says "child". Whoops!

Comment: When you use child themes, you want to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. There's a good explanation [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri).

Comment: Ok I will try to use the Masonry from Wordpress. I added the code above and now the page is loading and the script is enqued. Have to find a way to go from here.

Comment: Please close this question and ask a new one if you continue to run into problems.

Comment: @mevius: I have accepted your answer and will post a new one. Thanks